# Number of cucumber seedlings to grow together

Tags: cucumbers

I've have some cucumber seedlings planted in biodegradable pots. I planted the seeds two to a pot and have some pots where both seeds germinated.

Will there be an impact on production from plants growing close to each other, should I thin to one per pot?

The varieties are Femspot F1 and Piccoli Di Parigi

Comment: I often will allow two plants growing in the same starter pot to coexist.  I've never noticed a lack of vigor.  Cucumbers are fairly 'communal'.  Will you be planting these in the out of doors garden or in larger pots?  If these starts go out of doors from an in doors environment, do not forget to acclimate for a couple of weeks before planting in the out of doors garden.  Easy way to ruin all of your time and work. Have you grown cucumbers before?  Do you make pickles??

Comment: @MarkWilliams Just wondering, how big are your pots?

Comment: @stormy I've grown cucumbers outdoors before but these will be going undercover in a polytunnel. My plan is to pickle the piccolo di parigi cucumbers. I'll be sure to harden them off.

Comment: @Ljk2000 They'll be going into 12" pots I expect.

Answer (score 2):

The mature plants should be spaced at 18inches/45cm apart in the ground or in growbags, to allow for spread sideways, so clearly, two plants growing within an inch or two of each other isn't a great thing. You should remove the spare seedlings - if you want to, you could try taking them out carefully and growing on separately, each with their own cell or pot. Growing info for Femspot here http://www.dtbrownseeds.co.uk/Vegetable-Seeds-1/Indoor_3/Cucumber-Indoor-Femspot-F1-Seeds.html#.WtiYqeTTUn4

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably cut the weaker seeding out to avoid disturbing the roots of the remaining one. From what I understand cucumbers do not respond well to any root disturbance.

Comment: That is good, Mark.  Cut one off and ensure the other survives.